# Trying to change names of files using Dir and File.rename on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm following a tutorial and am trying to change the names of three files in a folder that's located under 'drive/users/myname/test'. I'm getting the error:

```
'chdir': No such file or directory - test'.
```

The starting path is already 'drive/users/myname', which is why I thought that I only had to enter 'test' for `Dir.chdir`.

How do I correctly input the paths on Mac OS?

```
Dir.chdir('test')

pic_names = Dir['test.{JPG,jpg}']

puts "What do you want to call this batch"
batch_name = gets.chomp
puts
print "Downloading #{pic_names.length} files:  "


pic_number = 1
pic_names.each do |p|
  print '.'
  new_name = "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"

  File.rename(name, new_name)
  pic_number += 1
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to provide the absolute path. So, your first line should be:

```
Dir.chdir("/drive/users/myname/test")
```

According to the documentation:

```
Dir.chdir("/var/spool/mail") 
puts Dir.pwd
```

should output`/var/spool/mail`.

You can look at the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
File.rename(name, new_name)
```

`name` is never defined prior to its attempted use.

Perhaps `p` is supposed to be `name`, or `name` should be `p`?

With that assumption I'd write the loop something like:

```
pic_names.each_with_index do |name, pic_number|
  print '.'
  new_name = "#{ batch_name }#{ 1 + pic_number }.jpg"

  File.rename(name, File.join(File.dirname(name), new_name))
end
```

`File.join(File.dirname(name), new_name)` is important. You have to refer to the same path in both the original and new filenames, otherwise the file will be moved to a new location, which would be wherever the current-working-directory points to. That's currently masked by your use of `chdir` at the start, but, without that, you'd wonder where your files went.